# Router to action with using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuetify.js

I'm learning vue.js and I'm using this code from Vuetify official web to practice with a pre-made layout. How can I do yo 
I mean that when you press one of the buttons on the side menu, load the information elsewhere without having to refresh the page

Thanks in advance...

```
<template>

  <v-app id="inspire">

    <v-navigation-drawer

      v-model="drawer"

      :clipped="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp"

      app

    >

      <v-list dense>

        <template v-for="item in items">

          <v-row

            v-if="item.heading"

            :key="item.heading"

            align="center"

          >

            <v-col cols="6">

              <v-subheader v-if="item.heading">

                {{ item.heading }}

              </v-subheader>

            </v-col>

            <v-col

              cols="6"

              class="text-center"

            >

              <a

                href="#!"

                class="body-2 black--text"

              >EDIT</a>

            </v-col>

          </v-row>

          <v-list-group

            v-else-if="item.children"

            :key="item.text"

            v-model="item.model"

            :prepend-icon="item.model ? item.icon : item['icon-alt']"

            append-icon=""

          >

            <template v-slot:activator>

              <v-list-item-content>

                <v-list-item-title>

                  {{ item.text }}

                </v-list-item-title>

              </v-list-item-content>

            </template>

            <v-list-item

              v-for="(child, i) in item.children"

              :key="i"

              link

            >

              <v-list-item-action v-if="child.icon">

                <v-icon>{{ child.icon }}</v-icon>

              </v-list-item-action>

              <v-list-item-content>

                <v-list-item-title>

                  {{ child.text }}

                </v-list-item-title>

              </v-list-item-content>

            </v-list-item>

          </v-list-group>

          <v-list-item

            v-else

            :key="item.text"

            link

          >

            <v-list-item-action>

              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>

            </v-list-item-action>

            <v-list-item-content>

              <v-list-item-title>

                {{ item.text }}

              </v-list-item-title>

            </v-list-item-content>

          </v-list-item>

        </template>

      </v-list>

    </v-navigation-drawer>



    <v-app-bar

      :clipped-left="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp"

      app

      color="blue darken-3"

      dark

    >

      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer" />

      <v-toolbar-title

        style="width: 300px"

        class="ml-0 pl-4"

      >

        <span class="hidden-sm-and-down">Google Contacts</span>

      </v-toolbar-title>

      <v-text-field

        flat

        solo-inverted

        hide-details

        prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"

        label="Search"

        class="hidden-sm-and-down"

      />

      <v-spacer />

      <v-btn icon>

        <v-icon>mdi-apps</v-icon>

      </v-btn>

      <v-btn icon>

        <v-icon>mdi-bell</v-icon>

      </v-btn>

      <v-btn

        icon

        large

      >

        <v-avatar

          size="32px"

          item

        >

          <v-img

            src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/logos/logo.svg"

            alt="Vuetify"

          /></v-avatar>

      </v-btn>

    </v-app-bar>

    <v-content>

      <v-container

        class="fill-height"

        fluid

      >

        <v-row

          align="center"

          justify="center"

        >

          <v-tooltip right>

            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">

              <v-btn

                :href="source"

                icon

                large

                target="_blank"

                v-on="on"

              >

                <v-icon large>mdi-code-tags</v-icon>

              </v-btn>

            </template>

            <span>Source</span>

          </v-tooltip>

          <v-tooltip right>

            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">

              <v-btn

                icon

                large

                href="https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/MNYLdL"

                target="_blank"

                v-on="on"

              >

                <v-icon large>mdi-codepen</v-icon>

              </v-btn>

            </template>

            <span>Codepen</span>

          </v-tooltip>

        </v-row>

      </v-container>

    </v-content>

    <v-btn

      bottom

      color="pink"

      dark

      fab

      fixed

      right

      @click="dialog = !dialog"

    >

      <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>

    </v-btn>

    <v-dialog

      v-model="dialog"

      width="800px"

    >

      <v-card>

        <v-card-title class="grey darken-2">

          Create contact

        </v-card-title>

        <v-container>

          <v-row class="mx-2">

            <v-col

              class="align-center justify-space-between"

              cols="12"

            >

              <v-row

                align="center"

                class="mr-0"

              >

                <v-avatar

                  size="40px"

                  class="mx-3"

                >

                  <img

                    src="//ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/sge/grey_silhouette.png"

                    alt=""

                  >

                </v-avatar>

                <v-text-field

                  placeholder="Name"

                />

              </v-row>

            </v-col>

            <v-col cols="6">

              <v-text-field

                prepend-icon="mdi-account-card-details-outline"

                placeholder="Company"

              />

            </v-col>

            <v-col cols="6">

              <v-text-field

                placeholder="Job title"

              />

            </v-col>

            <v-col cols="12">

              <v-text-field

                prepend-icon="mdi-mail"

                placeholder="Email"

              />

            </v-col>

            <v-col cols="12">

              <v-text-field

                type="tel"

                prepend-icon="mdi-phone"

                placeholder="(000) 000 - 0000"

              />

            </v-col>

            <v-col cols="12">

              <v-text-field

                prepend-icon="mdi-text"

                placeholder="Notes"

              />

            </v-col>

          </v-row>

        </v-container>

        <v-card-actions>

          <v-btn

            text

            color="primary"

          >More</v-btn>

          <v-spacer />

          <v-btn

            text

            color="primary"

            @click="dialog = false"

          >Cancel</v-btn>

          <v-btn

            text

            @click="dialog = false"

          >Save</v-btn>

        </v-card-actions>

      </v-card>

    </v-dialog>

  </v-app>

</template>



<script>

  export default {

    props: {

      source: String,

    },

    data: () => ({

      dialog: false,

      drawer: null,

      items: [

        { icon: 'mdi-contacts', text: 'Contacts' },

        { icon: 'mdi-history', text: 'Frequently contacted' },

        { icon: 'mdi-content-copy', text: 'Duplicates' },

        {

          icon: 'mdi-chevron-up',

          'icon-alt': 'mdi-chevron-down',

          text: 'Labels',

          model: true,

          children: [

            { icon: 'mdi-plus', text: 'Create label' },

          ],

        },

        {

          icon: 'mdi-chevron-up',

          'icon-alt': 'mdi-chevron-down',

          text: 'More',

          model: false,

          children: [

            { text: 'Import' },

            { text: 'Export' },

            { text: 'Print' },

            { text: 'Undo changes' },

            { text: 'Other contacts' },

          ],

        },

        { icon: 'mdi-settings', text: 'Settings' },

        { icon: 'mdi-message', text: 'Send feedback' },

        { icon: 'mdi-help-circle', text: 'Help' },

        { icon: 'mdi-cellphone-link', text: 'App downloads' },

        { icon: 'mdi-keyboard', text: 'Go to the old version' },

      ],

    }),

  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is vue-router (`npm i vue-router`) and then set up your main.js page as below

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
import About from './components/About.vue'
import Contact from './components/Contact.vue'

import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { name: 'home', path: '/', component: Home},
    { name: 'about', path: '/about', component: About},
    { name: 'contact', path: '/contact', component: Contact}
  ]
})

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

And in App.vue you need to load `<router-view>`

```
<template>
  <keep-alive>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </keep-alive>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "App"
};
</script>
```

You can simply add some href `<a href="/about">About</a>` to navigate between the pages, or you can use `:to` attribute in `v-btn`, If you have some other vuetify element which don't `:to` attribute then you can wrap the element in `<router-link>`

```
<router-link :to="/about">
  <span>About</span>
</router-link>
```